# How do you stop Google Chrome trying to open RSS feeds instead of showing the xml (which is what I want)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I am doing a little debugging and want to read the pure and simple rss xml response in Chrome and do not want Google Reader to be opened...how can this be done?

Thanks

P.S I don't use Google Reader so don't mind if it's permanently disabled.

Comment: I would love to have it the other way round. Now I see the XML in the browser, but I'd like to add the RSS to my reader.

Comment: @Marco As in you would like non rss xml to be rendered within Google reader? If you want rss rendered in a reader, try installing Google Reader http://www.google.com/reader

Comment: @James Have you tried viewing the RSS source via `Ctrl + U`?

Comment: +1 this terrible, terrible change in chrome is making my development much, much harder

Comment: @BryanDunsmore Yes I have, weirdly Chrome just refuses to show the source, just a blank page.

Comment: @KallDrexx I know right, it's not even like Google Reader fails gracefully and falls back on the classic view - if it feels unhappy about the xml it just shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

A recent article at [digital inspiration](http://www.labnol.org/) explains how to solve your problem: [Prevent Google Chrome from Hijacking RSS Feeds](http://www.labnol.org/internet/rss-feeds-in-google-chrome/24895/).

Answer (score 0):

This question is from 2012 but after Google give up on RSS it resurrected it and open builtin Chrome extension for RSS feeds. To disable that behavior you can remove that extension from Chrome. You can do that from Google Chrome Web store page for [RSS Subscription extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rss-subscription-extensio/nlbjncdgjeocebhnmkbbbdekmmmcbfjd). If the URL change just search the web store for it.